# Can't scrape some static image links from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the images from the landing page of a website. All the images are within `search_results` class name. When I run the script below, I get no results. I checked the `status_code` and could notice that the script is getting `403`.

[website link](https://pixabay.com/images/search/office/)

How can I scrape the image links using requests as the images are static and available in the page source?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://pixabay.com/images/search/office/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36',
}

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select(".search_results a > img[src]"):
    print(item.get("src"))
```

Any solution which is related to any browser simulator, as in selenium is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: HTTP 403 error means the server doesn't want to talk to you.  Maybe it thinks you're a bot (which you are).

Comment: Very useful comment @John Gordon. Thanks.

Comment: there is other problem - this page uses JavaScript to add items (turn off JavaScript in web broweser and check your url) but `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`. You can't get image even if you get status `200`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)` to control web browser which can run `JavaScript`

Comment: if you display `r.text` then you see HTML with information about CAPTCHA. There is also message `Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.` and `Please enable Cookies.` and this can explain problem `403` - it uses JavaScript and `Cookies` to check if it it real web browser.

Answer (score 3):

This uses [`Selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/). For some reason, however, it does not seem to find the images in headless mode:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.get('https://pixabay.com/images/search/office')
    images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.search_results a > img[src]') # wait for images to show up
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    for item in soup.select(".search_results a > img[src]"):
        print(item.get("src"))
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Prints:

```
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/09/09/22/workplace-1245776__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/08/18/26/write-593333__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/11/09/office-620822__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/05/02/21/50/home-office-336378__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/19/11/19/office-1209640__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/11/08/office-620817__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/26/13/09/cup-of-coffee-1280537__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/11/11/15/workplace-2303851__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/09/11/08/startup-594090__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/08/18/25/startup-593327__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/08/18/27/startup-593341__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/05/02/21/49/home-office-336373__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/09/11/11/office-594132__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/04/16/37/meeting-2284501__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/05/03/01/03/macbook-336704__340.jpg
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/11/21/27/desk-3076954__340.jpg
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
/static/img/blank.gif
```

Answer (score 2):

This page uses `JavaScript` and `Cookies` and this makes problems. It also checks other headers, not only `User-Agent`.

First: you have to use `requests.Session()` to keep cookies. Second: you have to load some page (ie. main page) to get these cookies. When you will have cookies then it will accept other URLs. Third: it check also other headers to send cookies.

I run page in browser and use `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox to copy all headers used by real browser and I start testing request with different headers. Finally I found it needs

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}
```

Other problem is that page uses `JavaScript` to load images when you scroll page ("lazy-loading") and some url are not in `scr` but in `data-lazy` and then `src` has `'blank.gif'`

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36',
    #"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    #"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    #"Connection": "keep-alive",
    #"Pragma": "no-cache",
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)  # it will use there hearders in all requests

# --- get cookies ---

url = 'https://pixabay.com/'

r = s.get(url)
print(r.status_code)  # 403 but it is not problem

# only for test 
#r = s.get(url)
#print(r.status_code)  # 200 because it already have cookies

# --- get images ---

url = 'https://pixabay.com/images/search/office/'

r = s.get(url)
print(r.status_code)
#print(r.text)

results = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

for item in soup.select(".search_results a > img[src]"):
    src = item.get("src")
    if src is not None and 'blank.gif' not in src:
        print('src:', src)
        results.append(src)
    else:
        src = item.get("data-lazy")
        print('data-lazy:', src)
        results.append(src)

print('len:', len(results))
```

Comment: Thanks @furas for your invaluable information. I really appreciate it. In my case, I'm still getting 403.

Comment: did you run exactly my code or did you make changes in own code? Did you use `Session` in all requests? It will keep cookies and use them in all requests. Did you add all headers to Session ? This way all requests will use all these headers. You can try to add other headers. In my example I always get `403` in first request - because it doesn't have cookies yet. But next request already have cookies and it get status `200`. But If I remove some headers then it also gets `403`

Comment: I tried exactly [the way](https://pastebin.com/QMejkVQ6) you suggested. This is the result I get `403`,`403`,`len: 0`. Thanks.

Comment: I also get `403, 403, len: 0`. We're all crazy.

Comment: I checked your code and it works for me. Maybe server doesn't like you for some reason. Server may have other methods to control users. If you runs many requests in short time then it may treats it as bot and block it. OR your IP is on blacklist and it blocks it. you can try to use some proxy server to send every requests with different IP. But free proxy server usually are useless - they won't work or they can be on blacklist and blocks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Pixabay is using Cloudflare's Web Application Firewall (WAF) or similar. This is quite tedious to get around manually.

`cloudflare-scrape` is a library that might be of assistance: https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape